# Status bar text is black after app go to background although 'light-content' is being used - iOS 15

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image: Only location usage is shown]
I am having a weird bug. I am using react-native 0.61.5 and react-navigation 4.0.10.
After my app goes to the background and the user enters it again, the status bar is not showing. I think that text transforms to black although I am using 'light-content'. This happened only on iOS 15. Do you know why this happens and is there a fix to this problem?
Big thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an iOS 15 bug, it happens only when dark mode is not turned on.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687801